# 3D Studio Max for beginners

Tags: resource-recommendations, 3ds-max

I would like to learn to use 3D Studio Max, but I cannot find any good tutorial to start with.

I bought the manual, but there it explains in details all the possible functions you can find in the software. The fact is that I never had a course about 3D modelling, therefore I need something really easy.

For example, when I learned to use Photoshop I just looked at thousands of tutorials and I learned the commands just following the instructions and then  trying to customize the results.

I would like to follow the same procedure for 3D Studio Max, the problem is that I found very few tutorials on that.

Answer (score 1):

First, I know you already have that book, but read more ;')
A good starting point would be to learn some 3D design concepts and terminologies, and what you can/should do with 3D programs >>

Flipped Normals has a great introduction on 3D digital design in general:

[Flipped Normals Introduction to 3D](http://flippednormals.com/introduction-3d/)

Take note of some clickable bars there with "+" sign that you can expand to read more, for example:

[image: Flipped Normals screenshot]

**I'm sure other people here can send you video tutorial resources.** Free ones preferably..? :') For now, read on :')